# Arduino udp ping

Tags: c#, arduino, router, lan

---

First to explain my goal I'm trying to control my robot to go forward, back, right, left and stop with UDP *(User Datagram Protocol)* protocol

- I'm using

  - Arduino Mini Atmega168
  - Lan ENC28J60
  - Router Tp-Link 150Mbps Wireless N Nano
  - Motor Driver L293D
- and Application in C# with buttons forward, back, left, right and stop

  arduino ip address is 192.168.178.60 I'm pinging that address without problem but **if I try to click faster on the buttons to control or click any button and leave it more time example to go forward it blocks or to left it blocks and I must restart arduino** to get my ping back.The main problem is why I lose my connection so fast.

Here is my code

```
#include "EtherShield.h"
//8 or 16 bit integer
uint8_t mymac[6] = {0xCF,0x70,0x7C,0xE4,0x8A,0xB8};
uint8_t myip[4] = {192,168,178,60};
uint16_t MYWWWPORT = 80; 

#define BUFFER_SIZE 750

static uint8_t buf[BUFFER_SIZE+1];

EtherShield es=EtherShield();

uint16_t dat_p;

///----------------------------------------------------------
void setup(){

Setup_Pins();
es.ES_enc28j60Init(mymac);
es.ES_init_ip_arp_udp_tcp(mymac,myip, MYWWWPORT);

} 


///----------------------------------------------------------

void loop(){

// read packet, handle ping and wait for a tcp packet:
buf[IP_PROTO_P]=0;
dat_p=es.ES_packetloop_icmp_tcp(buf,es.ES_enc28j60PacketReceive(BUFFER_SIZE, buf));

if (buf[IP_PROTO_P]==IP_PROTO_UDP_V){
    Motor_Control();
    buf[IP_PROTO_P]=0;
    }
} 


//----------------------------------------------------------

void Setup_Pins(){

    pinMode(4, OUTPUT); digitalWrite(4, 0);//lev
    pinMode(5, OUTPUT); digitalWrite(5, 0);//lev
    pinMode(6, OUTPUT); digitalWrite(6, 0);//desen
    pinMode(7, OUTPUT); digitalWrite(7, 0);//desen

} 

///----------------------------------------------------------

void Motor_Control(){

    char* recv = (char*)buf + 42;

// forward


    if (strncmp(recv, "forward", 7) == 0) { 
                    digitalWrite(4, 0);
                    digitalWrite(5, 1);
                    digitalWrite(6, 0);
                    digitalWrite(7, 1);
    }

//left


    if (strncmp(recv, "left", 4) == 0) { 
                    digitalWrite(4, 1);
                    digitalWrite(5, 0);
                    digitalWrite(6, 0);
                    digitalWrite(7, 1);
    }

//stop



    if (strncmp(recv, "stop", 4) == 0) { 
                    digitalWrite(4, 0);
                    digitalWrite(5, 0);
                    digitalWrite(6, 0);
                    digitalWrite(7, 0);
    }

//right


    if (strncmp(recv, "right", 5) == 0) { 
                    digitalWrite(4, 0);
                    digitalWrite(5, 1);
                    digitalWrite(6, 1);
                    digitalWrite(7, 0);
    }

//back


    if (strncmp(recv, "back", 4) == 0) { 
                    digitalWrite(4, 1);
                    digitalWrite(5, 0);
                    digitalWrite(6, 1);
                    digitalWrite(7, 0);
    }
        delay(6);

} 


///----------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your network stack, but `ES_packetloop_icmp_tcp` does not sound like it will work on **UDP** traffic. I'd assume it processes ICMP and/or TCP packets. ICMP is the type of packets used by the common `ping` command and ICMP is *not* the same as UDP.

Edit: Maybe [this](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/UDPSendReceiveString) helps to get you started.